# ngx-translate: Separate translation file for module does not load

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngrx, ngx-translate

I am currently trying to get a translation working for an Angular module in an NgRx project. For the translation I am using a ngx-translate and the whole project is based on a template called ["Angular NgRx Material Starter"](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter).

However, currently I am facing the problem that I have created a new module called "setup" that shall use a separate translation from the /assets/i18n/setup directory. To create the new module and a component in this module, I have used the Angular CLI.

Unfortunately the translation file does not load when I access the "devices" component in the "setup" module, so the page only shows the key of the string in the translation file. To show the problem, I have created a very simple example to reproduce the behavior with the base template. Since I am totally stuck here, any help is highly appreciated.

This a ZIP file containing the full project: [ngx-translate problem](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArdFApltDqiNgZ8G7SwEoc-2wZtmxw?e=qIwR75)

Any ideas?

**core.module.ts:** (loaded once at the beginning), the main translation is loaded:

```js
export {
  ...
};

export function httpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    http,
    `${environment.i18nPrefix}/assets/i18n/`,
    '.json'
  );
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
  ...
}
```

**shared.module.ts**: The "shared" module just imports and exports the TranslationModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  ...
}
```

**setup.module.ts:** The "setup" module looks like this:

```js
export function setupHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    http,
    `${environment.i18nPrefix}/assets/i18n/setup/`,
    '.json'
  );
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LazyElementsModule,
    SharedModule,
    SetupRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(FEATURE_NAME, reducers),
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: setupHttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    }),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [DevicesComponent]
})
export class SetupModule {
}
```

**devices.component.ts/.html**: This is the "devices" component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'anms-devices',
  templateUrl: './devices.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./devices.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DevicesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```html
<p>devices works!</p>
<h1>{{ 'setup.translation.test' | translate }}</h1>
```

**setup-routing.module.ts:** The "setup" routing module:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'devices',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'devices',
    component: DevicesComponent,
    data: { title: 'ecue.setup.devices.title' }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SetupRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer to the problem and it was quite simple (and maybe too obvious). In the newly created module I have created an effect that will set the language in the translation service for the sub-module:

```
setTranslateServiceLanguage = createEffect(
() => () =>
  this.store.pipe(
    select(selectSettingsLanguage),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap((language) => this.translateService.use(language))
  ),
 { dispatch: false }
);
```